# subfloatrow of package floatrow does not work without subcaptions

Tags: floatrow

I have two pictures that I want to place as subparts using the `floatrow` package.
The following example works if I add subcaptions to the parts, but does not if I leave them out.

I do not want any subcaptions for these parts.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
      \ffigbox{%
        \begin{subfloatrow}[2]%
          \ffigbox{%
            \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{fig1}%
          }{
            %\subcaption{} %% does not work without
          }%
          \ffigbox{%
            \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{fig2}%
          }{
            %\subcaption{} %% does not work without
          }%
        \end{subfloatrow}% 
      }{
        \caption{A caption}
      }
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `\phantomcaption` command to actually skip the caption of the subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{fig1}%
\phantomcaption
\label{fig:subfiga}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{fig1}%
\phantomcaption
\label{fig:subfigb}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A caption}
\label{fig:thefig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the `\phantomcaption` commant does not work in combination with the `floatrow` package.

Comment: @BjörnSteffen Do you need to use it? I've not used it in my answer anyway.

Comment: Yes I could disable `floatrow` for the current figure and just use your solution. Maybe its an odd behavior (or bug) of the `floatrow` package that it always requires a caption?!

Comment: @BjörnSteffen Or slowly getting outdated though it's a very nice package. I don't know if it is still actively supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the starred version of `\subcaption` with an empty argument; you will also need to correct the vertical spacing removing the default caption skip (`-10pt`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{captionskip=-10pt}%
\ffigbox{%
  \begin{subfloatrow}[2]%
    \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{fig1}}{\subcaption*{}}%
    \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{fig2}}{\subcaption*{}}%
  \end{subfloatrow}% 
}{\caption{A test caption}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hoped there is a cleaner way than using `\vskip-1.5\baselineskip`. But it seems that the `floatrow` package does not support float parts without captions inside `(sub)floatrow`.

Comment: @BjörnSteffen apparently not; I've updated my answer with a cleaner approach (although some correction is still applied).