# subfloatrow and tabularx, wrong numbering of figure

Tags: tables, numbering, captions, floatrow

I wanted to "group" a figure and a table to get one figure.
[It has been proposed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions) to use `floatrow` for this, with the possibility to remove the `subcaptions` later on ([subfloatrow of package floatrow does not work without subcaptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65236/subfloatrow-of-package-floatrow-does-not-work-without-subcaptions)).

But it seems, that the figure inside the environment will be counted (global figure number), even though it's in a `subfloatrow`!

The attached example shows the same source code with `tabularx` in the beginning and `tabular` in the end. One can see that the numbering starts with 2 instead of 1!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,tabularx,floatrow}

% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\ffigbox{
    \begin{subfloatrow}
        \ffigbox{%
          \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
        }{%
          \caption{A figure}%
        }
        \capbtabbox{%
          \begin{tabularx}{4cm}{cc} \hline
          Author & Title \\ \hline
          Knuth & The \TeX book \\
          Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
          \end{tabularx}
        }{%
          \caption{A table}%
        }
    \end{subfloatrow}
    }{%
      \caption{A figure and a table}%
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Has anybody an idea on how to prevent this? Is it a bug?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: An interesting problem you've come across! I've taken the liberty of streamlining your code to a "true" minimum working example (MWE) by removing unneeded packages, eliminating `blindtext`, and eliminating one of the two `figure` environments. Incidentally, what is the purpose of combining a (sub)figure environment and a tabular environment in a single `figure` environment? Cross-references to the tabular portions of a figure might come out looking quite awkward.

Comment: Hi Mico! Thanks for the cleaning-up ;-) !

In fact, the table references the figure, so I'd like them to be nicely joint together. Using a kind of meta-enviromnet (name it "scheme", e.g.) would be more logical, but rather tedious to work out...

Referencing the table, saying: "see Figure 1.b)" looks fine to me!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, and you do not want the subcaptions, you only need two `minipage` environments without extra packages.

To add subcaptions to the table and the figure without inferering the figure counter, one option could be the same, but adding the package `caption` and  using `\caption*` (with asterik) when needed. This is a  MWE: [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{/home/fran/MWE.png}
\end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \begin{tabularx}{4cm}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
  \caption{A figure and a table}%
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{/home/fran/MWE.png}
\caption*{The figure}
\end{minipage}\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\caption*{The table}
  \begin{tabularx}{4cm}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
  \caption{A figure and a table}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Fran!

Thanks for your example! I wanted to use as few ways of placing figures as possible in my work. So I found floatrow to be a very rich and flexible package to assist me with this.

I don't know why - but I kinda don't like minipages (no offence meant ;-) )!

But there may be times I'll have to use them.

After all, I can solve my problem without using tabularx but tabular, but I found this behaviour unexpected and disturbing, so I thouhgt to share it - maybe someone can fix this...