# How to get rid of subcaptions in an array of subfloats

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

I am using an array of figures using subfloat as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
{img_success/rgb/rgb_001456.eps}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
{img_success/rule/region_001456_1.eps}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
{img_success/map/region_001456_1.eps}}\\
\caption{Results on our dataset: Success case}
\label{tab:results_success}
\end{figure}
```

However, I get numberings below the subfigures like (a), (b),... How do I omit them? I tried applying

```
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{}
```

But this leaves empty parentheses "()".

How do I completely omit them?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Just leave out the `\subfloat[]{` part and the final closing brace.

Comment: Use the `\phantomcaption` command if this is using the `subcaption` package as you have tagged it.

Comment: here is the [demo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65237/15717) by percusse from his own answer

Comment: The purpose of `\subfloat` command is to give each sub-figure a caption and an automatically numbered label. If you don't want any of these, don't use `\subfloat`. You can still put all the `\includegraphics` in a single `figure` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `figure` environment can contain (almost) anything; it's by no means necessary that multiple images are enclosed in `\subfloat` commands. Thus

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=70pt,height=60pt]{img_success/rgb/rgb_001456}
\includegraphics[width=70pt,height=60pt]{img_success/rule/region_001456_1}
\includegraphics[width=70pt,height=60pt]{img_success/map/region_001456_1}}

\caption{Results on our dataset: Success case}
\label{tab:results_success}
\end{figure}
```

is exactly what you need. To TeX, the three images are just like big letters.

A normal space will be placed between the images; you can end the first two lines with `\quad` or `\qquad`, instead, for bigger space.

Don't use `px` based lengths, unless you have set the pixel width in the document. Prefer other units or fractions of the text width. It's also better to avoid extensions, so the document can be more easily ported to other engines such as `pdflatex`.

Comment: +1 but wouldn't you want to encourage the removal of the extensions? and perhaps use `graphicspath`?

Comment: @cmhughes You're right about the extensions. I'm not really a fan of `\graphicspath`.